# Is "whom" used correctly in this extract? :

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, relative-pronouns

*“Friends **whom** I have met later have told me that I was not one of those **whom** the shock of admission greatly depressed”.*

̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶_̶

I'm kind of confused here... In both cases I'd have used '*who*' instead of '*whom*'.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You met the friends. So you met **them**, not *they*. Similarly, we have ***Whom** did you meet?* rather than ***Who** did you meet.* The noun *friends* is the complement of *met*, so the coreference is made (in traditional usage) with *whom* rather than *who*.

Likewise, the shock did not depress **me**, not *I*. Similarly, we have ***Whom** did the shock depress?* rather than ***Who** did the shock depress?*

Now here’s the place where I point out that it is entirely idiomatic today to replace *whom* by *who* almost everywhere, with exceptions like the collocation *to **whom** it may concern*. Some speakers—and especially writers—do still use *whom* in all the traditional ways.